# How to create regex to validate string which contains only gmail.com?

Tags: java, regex

I have a text with emails. If the text contains `@gmail.com`, then the string is validate.

Example:

```
igoer@gmail.com igoesdr@gmail.com igoer@MAIL.ru igoer@gmail.com
```

I think the code for validation is: `^(.+@gmail.com).*$`

But this code doesn't work for me.

Comment: `but didn't work` ... _what_ didn't work?

Comment: Why it didn't work, it looks fine to me ( besides the maybe unnecessary .* at the end)

Answer (score 0):

try this @igor

```
(\W|^)[\w.+\-]*@gmail\.com(\W|$)
```

Comment: Your answer was flagged as "low quality". Please try to explain in a few sentences why or how this solution works.

Answer (score 0):

Try `^(*)(@gmail.com)$` or `.*\\b@gmail.com\\b`

I think your regex should do away with the `*` at the end, and it will work. The extra `*` at the end means that the input string should end with anything *after* *"@gmail.com"*. Your regex is searching for string like `xyz@gmail.com.xyz`, where `xyz` can be anything.

Answer (score 0):

Reading the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50527828/1) from the user and the [current edited version](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/50527828/3), the edits changed the question from the user.

A possible solution to the original not edited version which stated:

> I have a text with emails. If text has all mails @gmail.com - the
>   string is validate.

could be to repeat the email address which contains `@gmail` followed by a whitespace for the whole string assuming that the string consist of email addresses only.

[`^(?:\S+@gmail\.com )*\S+@gmail\.com$`](https://regex101.com/r/RRtBZb/1)

If there can be multiple whitespaces around the email addresses you might use:

[`^ *(?:\S+@gmail\.com(?: *|$))+$`](https://regex101.com/r/a9rM6p/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `.+` operator, see example:

```
public class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        String email = "gabrielpereira@gmail.com";
        System.out.println(email.matches(".+@gmail.com"));
    }
}
//returns true
```

The `.+` will check if exists 1 or more characters.